# Supercritical fluids polarity

Tags: physical-chemistry, polarity

Water is a polar solvent, but in the supercritical fluid state, it is much less polar, I presume because of the cleavage of hydrogen bonds. On the other hand, carbon dioxide is non-polar, but as a supercritical fluid it is more polar. Why is this so?

Comment: Geez, again this mixing of net dipole and solvent polarity, it doesn't matter much that CO2 has no net dipole.

Comment: It has a quadrupole moment, I guess it is related to it's polarity.