# Do all supercritical fluids dissolve the same substances?

Tags: phase

In the case of regular fluids, polar solvents dissolve polar molecules and nonpolar solvents dissolve nonpolar molecules. Is there something analogous for supercritical fluids? In other words, does the shape of the supercritical fluid molecule affect what it dissolves, or do all supercritical fluids dissolve the same set of substances?

Comment: Related: [Supercritical fluids polarity](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71871/supercritical-fluids-polarity) (no answer yet).